# How to hide all the Panels in a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I am using asp.net 4.

I need set up for all Panels WebControl for a page their visibility to false like

```
uxTypesDisplayer.Visible = false;
```

I need to setup visibility for all this panel without mention the single ID for every single panel.

Do you know guys how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void HidePanelsRecursively(Control container)
{
    if (container is Panel)
        container.Visible = false;

    foreach (Control ctrl in container.Controls)
        HidePanelsRecursively(ctrl);
}
```

And then just call it like this in your Page's code-behind:

```
HidePanelsRecursively(this);
```

Comment: I think this is your best bet based on your comment response to Stefanvds.

Answer (score 1):

In the code-behind, you can just put everything in one parent `Panel` and set it's `Visible` property to false;

Comment: good idea too, depends on what he really is trying to achieve with this :)

Answer (score 0):

why do you need this?

are you trying to show no panel by default, and then by some logic display 1 or more of them?

in this case, add the parameter `visible="false"` in your aspx page for each panel.